# Avoid malicious code to be sent to FirebaseDatabase via chat on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an application that has a chat implemented with `FirebaseDatabase`, like the one shown in this codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0

The problem is: the user is free to send anything on chat, is it possible to block code like HTML or JS to be sent, to avoid security problems, or this can be treated only when reading messages sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done adding this method to the text sent via chat:

```
 private fun removeHTMLCode(text: String?) = text?.replace("<[^>]*>".toRegex(), "")?.trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

On the user side you can remove HTML tags when submiting the message:

```
str = str.replaceAll("<(.*?)\\>", " ");//Removes all items in brackets
str = str.replaceAll("<(.*?)\\\n", " ");//Must be undeneath
str = str.replaceFirst("(.*?)\\>"," ");//Removes any connected item to the last bracket
str = str.replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");
str = str.replaceAll("&amp;", " ");
```

Also by default, most HTML tags won't be executed in your TextView unless you used `fromHtml` function.